# OpenCV 2.4.9 - how to compile C source files which use video API?

Tags: c, linux, opencv, header, header-files

I would like to compile a C program using OpenCV2.4.9 libraries in Linux.

The main file  includes a SterTri.h header:

**SterTri.c**

```
#include "SterTri.h"    

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
 [...]
}
```

In the header file, the following libraries are included:

**SterTri.h**

```
#ifndef STERTRI_H
#define STERTRI_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <cvaux.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h> // per fork() /* UNIX standard function definitions */
#include <sys/wait.h> // per wait()
#include <fcntl.h>   /* File control definitions */
#include <errno.h>   /* Error number definitions */
#include <termios.h> /* POSIX terminal control definitions */
#include "RicCerc.h"
#define PI 3.1415926535898
#define WIDTH 640
#define HEIGHT 480
#define ANGOLO 0.401425728


IplImage * LR_Img = NULL;
IplImage * RR_Img = NULL;
IplImage * L_Gray = NULL;
```

The compilation command:

```
gcc SterTri.c RicCerc.c -o program `pkg-config opencv --libs --cflags opencv`
```

returns the following errors:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv/cvaux.h:54:0,
                     from SterTri.h:7,
                     from SterTri.c:21:
    /usr/local/include/opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp:47:16: fatal error: list: File o directory non esistente
     #include <list>
                    ^
    compilation terminated.
    In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv/cvaux.h:54:0,
                     from RicCerc.h:7,
                     from RicCerc.c:1:
    /usr/local/include/opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp:47:16: fatal error: list: File o directory non esistente
     #include <list>
                    ^
    compilation terminated.
```

I get the same error due to a double inclusion of the header file `cvaux.h`. The compilation errors tells us that the `<list>` library is missing.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: `<list>` is a c++ header. you need g++, not gcc, to compile it.

Comment: also, if it's using cvaux headers, it must be terribly old / outdated.

Comment: Ok that was the problem. Thanks. Now I have other issues related to the c program. But I will deal with it.